# css3 rotate just the background or the mask

Tags: css

I was wondering if it is possible to rotate just the background image or mask with CSS3. The css3 transform rotate, rotates the whole element.

I failed googleing, maybe someone has an idea?

webkit example:
http://jsfiddle.net/meo/Atjdq/1/ (i want to rotate just the mask or alternatively the background)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you have to use a separate element, containing just the background image (or mask), if you want to rotate the background (or mask) independently.

Something like this, perhaps? http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/k9t5e/1/

Comment: oh so its possible to apply a mask on a image that is in a different element?

Comment: @meo: I'm not sure what you mean. The mask is independent of the background. As I understand it, it masks the entire element, not just the background. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/B7uLU/

Comment: @meo: is this something like the effect you're going for? http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/k9t5e/1/

Comment: ahhhh ok thank you! so i can rotate the image inside a parent div that has the mask for example. Thank you